# How to convert JSON String to Map in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am having JSON String passed from POST method of REST URL. I need to convert  json string to map of type Map

JSON String looks like below

```
{"key_value": {"1":"1000","2":"2000"}}
```

How to convert into Map using scala.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a JSON parser library. Here it is with `play-json`:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
val jsonString = """{"key_value": {"1":"1000","2":"2000"}}"""
val aMap = (Json.parse(jsonString) \ "key_value").as[Map[String,String]]
```

Documentation for the path operations: [https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Simple-path-\](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Simple-path-%5C)

If you're using SBT, you can import it like this:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-json_2.11" % "2.5.5"
```

Comment: .Thanks for the answer.I need to remove "key_value" from  `"""{"key_value": {"1":"1000","2":"2000"}}"""` input string. Only this part i need to put in map  {"1":"1000","2":"2000"} .

Comment: @Gopi Updated with just the value, not the key

Comment: Is it not possible with using play-json . Can we use something link json4s or iterate and put in map

Comment: Getting below error when doing the above 'Error:(170, 59) bad symbolic reference. A signature in DefaultReads.class refers to term time
in package java which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling DefaultReads.class.
      val aMap = (Json.parse(jsonString) \ "key_value").as[Map[Integer, Long]]'

Comment: That version might only work with java 8. Try version: 2.4.8